# Making dynamic queries for linked server in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to create a dynamic query in SQL Server which will run on linked server. I am trying to do it as follows.

```
USE [MYDB]
GO

DECLARE @company AS nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @id nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX);

SET @company = 'mycompany.com';
SET @query = N'SELECT @csid = id FROM OPENQUERY(LINKSERVER12, 
   ''SELECT id from company where name = @comp'')';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @company_query, N'@comp nvarchar(50), @csid 
nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT', @comp = @company,@csid = @id OUTPUT
```

In the above script, I want to pass the value for `@comp` dynamically. For that I tried setting input and output variable while executing SQL with `sp_executesql`.

I am getting the following error

> Syntax error in SQL statement. Syntax error line 1 at or after token .[10179].
>
> Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
>   An error occurred while preparing the query "SELECT id from company where name = @comp" for execution against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKSERVER12".

The error is happening at the dynamic query

```
N'SELECT @csid = id FROM OPENQUERY(LINKSERVER12, 
   ''SELECT id from company where name = @comp'')'
```

I tried replacing `@comp` in the SQL query with '`'@comp''`, `''''@comp''''` with no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you use "SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF" then you can delimit the string query using double quotes instead of single quotes. This doesn't solve your issue but it does prevent you from having to escape one set of your single quotes.

Comment: Could you try with `EXEC  LINKSERVER12.master.dbo.sp_executesql N'SELECT id from company where name = @comp', N'@comp nvarchar(50), @csid 
nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT', @comp = @company,@csid = @id OUTPUT ` ? Something similar to it. It allows you to avoid multi-layered quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Just build the string query wihtout parameters.

```
USE [companyDB]
GO

DECLARE
    @companyName AS nvarchar(50)
    ,@id nvarchar(MAX)
    ,@query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @companyName = 'AMAZON'

DECLARE @idTable TABLE
(
    id INT
)

--Repace Server, UID and PWD
SET @query = 
N'SELECT 
    [id]
FROM OPENROWSET
(
    N''SQLNCLI''
    ,N''Server=10.111.1.111;UID=username;PWD=password123;''
    ,N''SELECT [id]
       FROM [companyDB]
       WHERE [name] = '''''+@companyName+'''''''
)'

INSERT INTO @idTable
EXECUTE (@query)

SELECT TOP 1
    @id = id
FROM @idTable
```